# Rendering Partial with specific :category_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, renderpartial

I created a `Categories Scaffold`. User's can Upload an image and add a category to it.
The Categories i created in the Scaffold are shown in a dropdown for users to Select.

On the `Image Show Page` i link to the category ->

```
<%= link_to @pin.category.name, @pin.category%>
```

It takes me to (for example)

```
localhost:3000/categories/1
```

On the `Category Show Page` i want to display all the images which share the Same Category.

```
How do i do this ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Models you define that Catagory

> has_many :images

and Image

> belongs_to :category

- image should have category_id member of course

Then , when you have category object in hand (let's say @cat), you simply iterate @cat.images

You can read more about Models and Relation in here

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: If you need to add the category_id member, don't forget to rake db:migrate

Comment: I have Categories and Pins, but when i go to app/views/categories/show.html.erb how do i render the pins with the SPECIFIC category_id ?